# Function 'not declared in this scope' when using class in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a basic program that allows users to play each other in othello, and right now I'm just trying to initialize a blank array that represents the board and display it. I've worked with classes a few times, and my code doesn't seem to be any different from the other classes I've made, but I can't find why my functions aren't properly declared. The errors are:

```
othello.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
othello.cpp:9:17: error: ‘generateBoard’ was not declared in this scope
   generateBoard();
             ^
othello.cpp:10:13: error: ‘addBorder’ was not declared in this scope
   addBorder();
         ^
othello.cpp:11:18: error: ‘displayOthello’ was not declared in this
   scope
   displayOthello();
              ^
make: *** [othello.o] Error 1
```

Here is othelloboard.h

```
const int boardSize = 4;

class othelloboard{
  public:
    othelloboard();
    ~othelloboard();
    void generateBoard();
    void addBorder();
    void displayOthello();

  private:
    char othelloArray[boardSize][boardSize];
};
```

Here is othelloboard.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "othelloboard.h"

//Initialize global variables
extern const int boardSize;

othelloboard::othelloboard(){}
othelloboard::~othelloboard(){}

void othelloboard::generateBoard(){
  for (int i=1; i<= boardSize; i++){
    for (int j=1; j<= boardSize; j++){
      othelloArray[i][j] = '.';
    }
  }
}

void othelloboard::addBorder(){
  for (int i=1; i<= boardSize; i++){
    char temp = (char)i + '0';
    othelloArray[0][i] = temp;
    othelloArray[i][0] = temp;
  }
}

void othelloboard::displayOthello(){
  for (int i=0; i<= boardSize; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<= boardSize; j++){
      cout << othelloArray[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Here is Othello.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "othelloboard.h"

int main(){
  extern const int boardSize;
  cout << boardSize << endl;
  generateBoard();
  addBorder();
  displayOthello();
}
```

I also know global variables aren't the greatest, but we were instructed to use a global variable for board size.

Comment: Don't you instantiate your `othelloboard` class anywhere?

Comment: Move the code of generateBoard to the constructor, and drop that method. That will make the usage more natural.

Comment: Also `(char) i` does not do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to call the methods implemented in othelloboard.cpp, you have to create an object of type `othelloboard` inside `main()`, then you can simply call the methods using `objectName.methodName()`. Basically you have to do the following:

1. Create the object of type `othelloboard`:

   `othelloboard ob;`
2. Call your methods using

   `ob.generateBoard();`

etc